# Google Biq query something returns a null / no rows

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-bigquery

Querying Big Query using python api sometimes returns a No response or No rows .Though retrying the same query again works fine. Whats the reason for this ?

```
def execute(self,bq_query,query_type,uid):
    self.cache = cache.Cache()

    cached_response = self.cache.get(bq_query)
    if(cached_response is not None):
        query_response = json.loads(zlib.decompress(cached_response))
        app.logger.info("cached")
    else:
        big_query=_BigQuery(uid)
        query_response = big_query.run_in_big_query(bq_query)
        if not query_response:
            logging.warning('**************************1.No reponse')
            abort(404)
        elif 'rows' not in query_response.keys():
            logging.warning('**************************2.No rows')
            abort(404)



def run_in_big_query(self, sql):
    start = time.time()
    queryData = {'query': sql}
    queryRequest = self.service.jobs()
    queryResponse = queryRequest.query(projectId=project_id, 
body=queryData).execute()
    app.logger.info('Query Time %f' % (time.time() - start))
    return queryResponse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query method inserts a query job into BigQuery. By default, query method runs  with `10s` for [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query). When a non-zero timeout value is specified, the job will wait for the results, and throws an exception on timeout.

Read more about

- Synchronous queries
- Asynchronous queries

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data

also there you have Python code, how to poll until the job is complete.